Is there a way to start a windows gui application on an EC2 instance without a gui environment (no remote desktop connection, etc.)?
I can't start a windows GUI application on an EC2 instance without a GUI environment (no remote desktop connection, etc.). Is there any solution?
Thing I want to do
I want to start an EC2 instance with a custom AMI that has downloaded a windows native gui application, and start the windows gui application based on a command.
Environment
Instance: g5.2xlarge
ami: Created as a custom AMI based on NICE DCV for Windows (g4 and g5 with NVIDIA gaming driver) by additionally downloading a windows native gui application.
Things I tried
I created a bat file to start the windows gui application and set the task scheduler to run the bat file immediately after starting the instance. After starting the instance, I connected to the remote desktop using fleet manager and entered the instance, but the gui application was not started. There was no corresponding application in the process.
We have confirmed that if you run a bat file via task scheduler (set to start after 1 minute, etc.) while connected to a remote desktop, the application will start.
